# Oracle sql Order By number and char inside

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm quite new to sql so I don't fully understand what I'm doing. My question is, how can I order by this data, that the order would go by number like 1,2,3, but there are letters inside, so it would be like 1,2,A3, B3, 4.

I have this so far:

ORDER BY
REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '\d', 1, 1)),'(\d+.)(\d+.)?(\d+.)?(\d+.)?', '\1') NULLS FIRST,
REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '\d', 2, 2)),'(\d+.)(\d+.)?(\d+.)?(\d+.)?', '\2') NULLS FIRST,
REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '\d', 3, 3)),'(\d+.)(\d+.)?(\d+.)?(\d+.)?', '\3') NULLS FIRST,
REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '\d', 4, 4)),'(\d+.)(\d+.)?(\d+.)?(\d+.)?', '\4') NULLS FIRST,
REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '\d', 5, 5)),'(\d+.)(\d+.)?(\d+.)?(\d+.)?', '\5') NULLS FIRST,
string

it works until we have a third level decimal, like 2.7.1., then it goes like 2.1, 2.2...2.7,2.8, 2.7.1., 2.7.2. I don't know if I'm explaining it correctly so I have pic too :D

When it's like this it works:
[Picture of Working sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyNrQ.png)

[Picture of Working sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyNrQ.png)

But then we have numbers like 2.7.1., 2.7.2.
[Picture with incorrect sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TynA1.png)

So the plan is that it would sort number with string too, like: 1,2,A3,A3.1, A3.1.1. B3,B3.1,4.1, 4.1.1, 4.1.2...

Thank you so much for your help and explaining.

Comment: Please don't upload images, but provide the table structure, input data and expected outcome as tables, best would be a fiddle.

Comment: You have explained this well, I think. You should, however, be precise as to the strings' format. How many tokens are allowed in a string? Can only the first token be preceded with a letter or all tokens? Can there be more than one letter, e.g. AB12? What is the maximum length for a token? What is the maximum number of digits in a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you are incrementing the positionas well as the occurrence; so

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '\d', 2, 2)
```

should be

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '\d', 1, 2)
```

But you're overcomplicating it, and not handling multiple-digit elements, either when extracting or when sorting as nothing is treated as a number.

I think this does what you want:

```
ORDER BY
  TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '\d+', 1, 1)) nulls first,
  TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '\d+', 1, 2)) nulls first,
  TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '\d+', 1, 3)) nulls first,
  TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '\d+', 1, 4)) nulls first,
  TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '\d+', 1, 5)) nulls first,
  string
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f9485147c1653e7286fa9b7a484c0558)

---

If only the first element can start with a character (or characters), then you just just add a check for that after the first digit:

```
ORDER BY
  TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '\d+', 1, 1)) nulls first,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '^\w+', 1, 1) nulls first,
  TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '\d+', 1, 2)) nulls first,
  TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '\d+', 1, 3)) nulls first,
  TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '\d+', 1, 4)) nulls first,
  TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '\d+', 1, 5)) nulls first
```

which will order `3,A3,A3.1,B3`.

You might not need the `string` at the end now.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c7e12cdcdf076776267695bbe51a6fe4)

Comment: Well yes, at first my lines were simple, similar to this: 

ORDER BY
  TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '\d+', 1)),
  TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '\d+', 2)),
  TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '\d+', 3)),
  TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '\d+', 4)),
  TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '\d+', 5)),
  string

and the outcome was good, but the problem was with letter, it did not go in line A3, A3.1, A3.2, B3, B3.1. It was changing like: A3, B3, A3.1, B3.1. and then I tried to experiment with it and I was left with the first exmp.

Comment: @Rennie - yes, I'd *over*-simplified it, and hadn't noticed the result wasn't quite right. Hopefully fixed now. I'm confused about the letters though - your version seemed to be ignoring them; but you want to include those? Is it only a single letter in the first element? What order should `3,A3,B3` appear in?

Comment: Imagine the A3 to have a value just a tiny bit higher than a 3. And the B3 again a tiny bit more. Then you get 2 < A2 < B2 < 3 < A3 < B3 < 4 < A4 < B4. This is how I understand it.

Comment: Wow, with this approach, this suddenly looks so simple. You can just alternately order by the number and the non-number. `ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '\d+', 1, 1)) nulls first, REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '\D+', 1, 1) nulls first, TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '\d+', 1, 2)) nulls first, REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '\D+', 1, 2) nulls first,` etc. Here is a fiddle with my query and your altered one: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1838ab30bc0c62e00941ec2c2aa648ca. They both result in the same order. Seems I was overcomplicating this :-)

Comment: Thank you guys so much, it works. I see that I need to study regex more and put more work in it.

Comment: @Rennie Alpikort: Yep, getting good in regex is really worth the learning effort. Alex's answer is limited to a maximum number of tokens in a string. My answer is limited to a maximum number of digits in a number. I like Alex's answer a tad better than mine for its simplicity. If Alex's answer solves your problem, then accept it by clicking the tick/check next to it.

Answer (score 1):

What you mainly need is an idea how to approach this. As a human I can easily see what you are sorting these strings by: 1,2,A3,A3.1, A3.1.1. B3,B3.1,4.1, 4.1.1, 4.1.2..., but a computer wouldn't know that an A3 is to be treated as 3 plus a little and B3 as 3 plus a little more. And as these are strings, the computer won't understand either why '2' is to be sorted before '10' when it comes to numbers with more than one digit, because the string '10' starts with a '1', while the string '2' starts with a '2', which comes after '1'.

Let's start with the first problem. The computer doesn't see '3' < 'A3' < 'B3' < '4', but it would see '3' < '3A' < '3B' < '4'. So why not switch positions:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '([[:alpha:]])([[:digit:]]+)', '\2\1')
```

Then we must address the second problem. The computer doesn't see '1' < '2' < '10', but it would see '01' < '02' < '10'. So, optimally we would precede all numbers with leading zeros, so they all have the same length. For this to be possible, we must know the longest length allowed for a number. Let's say it is three places, like in '123' and 'B123'. Then we must make all numbers three digit numbers ('012', '012A', '123', '123B'). Unfortunately regular expressions cannot do that (or I don't know how). I'd have to kind of hard code: "find one-digit numbers and make them three-digit numbers" and "find two-digit numbers and make them three-digit numbers". And still I'd have to trick myself through this by adding unnecessary zeros first and then remove them again.

Here is the whole thing combined:

```
select
  col, 
  regexp_replace(
    regexp_replace(
      regexp_replace(
        regexp_replace(col,
                       '([[:alpha:]])([[:digit:]]+)',
                       '\2\1' -- step 1: switch number / alpha positions
        ),
        '([[:digit:]]+)',
        '00\1' -- step 2: precede all numbers with two zeros
      ),
      '0([[:digit:]]{4,4})',
      '\1' -- step 3: remove one leading zero from five-digit numbers
    ),
    '0([[:digit:]]{3,3})',
    '\1' -- step 4: remove one leading zero from (now) four-digit numbers
  ) as sortkey
from mytable
order by sortkey;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=dd21d406a88846285fed1d3c05595417

Or write a PL/SQL function to generate the sortkey.